# typescript handler where this[] = value

Tags: typescript

The following typescript function was in a class I was going to use and the assignment of this[col]= is something I would like to understand further, does this mean I can access col in the parent class or is this another way of returning it to the caller?

```
export class DemoResponsiveRows implements OnDestroy {
private _activeMQC : MediaChange;
private _watcher : Subscription;

firstCol = "row";
firstColXs = 'column';
firstColMd = 'column';
firstColLg = 'invalid';
firstColGtLg = "column";

secondCol = "column";

isVisible = true;

constructor(@Inject(MatchMediaObservable) private _media$) {
this._watcher = this._media$
    .subscribe((e:MediaChange) => {
      this._activeMQC = e;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
this._watcher.unsubscribe();
}

toggleLayoutFor(col) {
switch( col ) {
  case 1:

    col = `firstCol${this._activeMQC ? this._activeMQC.suffix : ""}`;
    this[col] = (this[col] === "column") ? "row" : "column";
    break;

  case 2:
    col = "secondCol";
    this[col] = (this[col] == "row") ? "column" : "row";
    break;
}}}
```

Comment: Changed to complete class example that I was trying to understand

Comment: Given the updated question, we can now see that `_activeMQC ` will either be undefined or will have a property of  "Xs", "Md", "Lg" or "GtLg". Since the suffix value can change dynamically during runtime, the code that you are asking about computes the value of `col` at run time to be "firstCol", "firstColXs", "firstColMd", "firstColLg", or "firstColGtLg". It then toggles the value of that variable to "Column" if it is "Row" or vice-versa. In the case of "firstColLg" where the value is original 'invalid', it would set it to "column".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is very confusing, so I won't try to explain the reasoning for why the code is written as is, only what it is doing. Also, I'd like to point out that typescript has little or nothing to do with why the code is written in this form -- at best, the only role typescript might be playing is providing the Class construct that is being used, if the code is not ES6, which I doubt since it is using the backtick template literals.

That said, the method takes a parameter, `col`, but the provided value is completely being ignored, since the first statement overrides the value with a string value. The class has a property called `_activeMQC`, which may or may not be assigned; if assigned, it is expected to be an object with a property called suffix, which I can assume may or may not be assigned. So after the first statement, the value of `col` is either:

- "firstCol", if the `_activeMQC` property is undefined or is a falsy value.
- "firstColundefined", if the `_activeMQC` property has a value, but is not an object with a defined `suffix` property
- "firstCol<Suffix>", if the `_activeMQC` property is assigned and has a `suffix` property with a value of <Suffix>.

The second statement will find a property on the class with the name corresponding to the value of `col` and set it's value to "row" or "column". If the value of the property is neither "row" nor "column", it will set it to "column", otherwise it will toggle it between those values.

The last statement, `break;`, is completely unnecessary.

==UPDATE==

This update is in response to the question of whether it is correct to use dot notation (`this.col`) or bracket notation (`this["col"]`) in javascript.

I don't think either way is more correct than the other in Javascript. However, the more common way is to use dot notation, `this.col`, when possible.

One common reasons to use bracket notation, `this[col]`, instead is if the property name has spaces or special characters. For example, if a property was called "the property", then you couldn't use dot notation, but could use bracket notation, `this["the property"]`.

Another common reason for using bracket notation, as in the example you provided is if you needed to determine the property to access at run-time. For example, assume we have N properties, prop1, prop2, ..., propN and we want to assign the values 1, 2 ... N. We could do that as follows:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    this['prop' + i] = i;
}
```

With dot notation, you would have to assign each individually as:

```
this.prop1 = 1;
this.prop2 = 2;
...
this.propN = N;
```

Comment: thanks.  this was a code snippet and the class and its variables was not included.  I was trying to understand the assignment this[col] =  and is there another form such as this.col =  that is equivalent in the parent class or is this[col] = the correct way to set class variables in javascript?

Comment: I've updated the answer to also answer the question of which is correct.

Comment: Your answer was greatly appreciated! I upvoted you but I am new so I guess its not calculating it until i have more reputation...